# How to Load Balance 2 Internet Connections on a Windows 7 machine?

Tags: windows-7, network-adapter

It's sort of related to [this particular question](https://superuser.com/questions/108045/load-balance-with-lan-and-wi-fi), but that one is on Mac.  I am looking for similar solution on Windows 7.

I have 2 network connections:

- (Connection A) Wireless terminal connecting to
  ISP A (3G / EVDO internet provider)
- (Connection B) Broadband wired
  connection connecting to ISP B (Cable
  internet provider)

Both has access to the internet.

When I try connecting to a website and checking the networking tab on my Task Manager, I only see the network traffic being routed to only Connection A.

**Is there a way to make the computer to utilize both network (in a sense using all the bandwidth available from both the Cable ISP and the 3G / EVDO ISP) at the same time?**

If so, what do I need to do to set this up ... on Windows 7?

Here is a bit more info on my network connections (ipconfig /all):

```
PPP adapter Wireless Terminal:
IPv4: aa.bb.ccc.ddd(preferred)

Subnet mask: 255.255.255.255
Default Gateway: 0.0.0.0
DNS: aa.ee.f.ggg
     aa.ee.f.hhh
Primary Wins: jjj.ii.k.l
Secondary Wins: jjj.ii.k.m

Ethernet adapter LAN:
IPv4: 192.168.1.100 (connected to a router by wired that itself connect to a cable modem)
subnet mask: 255.255.255.0
Default gateway: 192.168.1.1 (the wireless router)
DHCP: 192.168.1.1 (the wireless router)
DNS: xxx.yy.zz.ww
     rr.sss.t.uuu
```

For my own privacy, I don't believe the actual number matters, the patterns are representative of the ip numbering scheme...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found a forum [thread](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/20290-42-simultaneous-multiple-internet-connections) that suggested the following...

So far, I tried it, but I don't see much success (meaning most traffic still ended up on only 1 NIC, although sometimes I see both network cards having some traffics)...

**Step 1**

In the registry key, I added a DWORD value to the following hive:

**HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\NetBT\Parameters**

New DWORD (32-bit) value: **RandomAdapter** and set its value to 1

After doing that I can see somewhat the network traffic being divided into both network adapters in the Task Manager, Networking tab.

**Step 2**
I change the Adapter Metric on both adapter to the same value per the following MSKB: [315088](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315088) & [258487](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/258487/EN-US/)