# Does Windows 7 split packets between wired and wireless connections?

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, ethernet

On an old Windows laptop, I always had to use the hardware switch to force it to use the wired internet connection, otherwise it would try to connect to wireless, and either fail or get poor speeds, and then not discover that it was also plugged in.    Though this is what my friends told me they did, I couldn't shake the feeling that this isn't what the wireless hardware switch was designed for.

On my newer Windows 7 machine, I don't seem to have this problem.  It did get me thinking, though: does/can Windows send some packets through the wireless connection for increased speed when I am also connected through a wired Ethernet cable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows 7 does not allow using several paths (e.g. Wifi + Ethernet) concurrently. One initiative to use multiple paths to maximize resource usage and increase redundancy is [Multipath TCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multipath_TCP), aka. MPTCP.

[RFC 6824](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6824) lays the foundations for MPTCP but so far it is experimental and Windows 7 does not support it. Apple iOS7 released a few weeks ago supports it and the Linux Kernel contains MPTCP's [reference implementation](http://multipath-tcp.org/pmwiki.php/Main/HomePage). MPTCP was used to break the [record](http://multipath-tcp.org/pmwiki.php?n=Main.50Gbps) of the fastest TCP connection (51.8 Gbps).

Comment: Funny knowledge, but was it relevant ?

Comment: Because Windows might adopt MPTCP in the future, thereby adding native support for splitting packets between wired and wireless connections? Otherwise yes there exist some applications to achieve it such as http://asurasoft.awardspace.com/abtmulticonnect.html or the one you mentioned.

Comment: I know Server 2012 R2 supports bonding multiple interfaces together for increased throughput, I don't know if it is MPTCP though.

Comment: Thanks, interesting, I didn't know about [NIC teaming](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh997031.aspx). It seems to be [available](http://cloudtidings.com/2012/04/02/windows-8-and-nic-teaming-modes-and-how-to/) in Windows 8.

Answer (score 0):

try these, exactly what you needed.

http://www.connectify.me/dispatch/

or you can see this post

[Using multiple wifi connections simultaneously on Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/141490/using-multiple-wifi-connections-simultaneously-on-windows)

Comment: Connectify Dispatch is $40 Lifetime or $25 per year. The other link doesn't apply here.

Comment: There is some old links still offer the old trials...