# Using 2 independent network lines to assure twice reliable connection windows 7

Tags: windows-7, networking, drivers, 3g, adsl2+

I have a very `unreliable 24M ADSL2+` connection and an `iPhone4S with unlimited data` and unlimited speed (5M where I live). Right now I can choose between a very unreliable but low ping and fast line or a high ping, low bandwidth reliable line. I know `µtorrent` knows how to use both for combined bandwidth, but I'd like to know if it's possible to install some kind of a driver which emulates one network interface but in reality is using `both lines for a fast and reliable` connection. Or can I configure windows to do this for me? I have `Windows 7 Ultimate x64`.

Comment: Check this thread: http://superuser.com/questions/140657/how-to-load-balance-2-internet-connections-on-a-windows-7-machine