# Share Connection Speed, Possible?

Tags: networking

is it possible to share the connection speed between two servers / PCs

example :
person A have a speed of 8mbps and person B have a speed of 2mbps
so the download speed of person A is more than the person B

i was wondering if person A can share his connection speed (to be a ISP) to person B , so person B may get more download speed ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Load Balance 2 Internet Connections on a Windows 7 machine?](http://superuser.com/questions/140657/how-to-load-balance-2-internet-connections-on-a-windows-7-machine)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes.  It's called load balancing.  However, the configuration can be a bit tricky and depends a lot on your available hardware and the specifics of the servers, their OSs, etc.

[This thread](https://superuser.com/questions/140657/how-to-load-balance-2-internet-connections-on-a-windows-7-machine) has some suggestions that will get you started.  For detailed help, you'll have to post a lot more information about your servers, connections, networking devices, etc., and what you have tried so far.